# Как послать UDP датаграмму через PHP...

Tags: php, c++

Как послать UDP датаграмму через PHP, а обработать этот запрос на другой стороне через c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем нет. Используйте соответствующие ф-ции для работы с пакетами.

В PHP это:

- [socket_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-create.php)
- [socket_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-connect.php)
- [socket_bind](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-bind.php)
- [socket_write](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-write.php) и
- [socket_close](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-close.php)

Для C/C++ смотрите ответ на похожий вопрос тут.

Comment: Эм? А можно линк?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/1608/как-изучать-winsock2-h